# How do I inspect the methods of a Ruby object?

Tags: ruby, introspection

I am wondering if there is a Ruby method call that shows only the methods defined by the Ruby object it's called from, as opposed to all the methods defined by its ancestor classes, which is what `methods` seems to do.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

`methods` takes an optional boolean parameter, which specifies whether to also list the methods from the object's class and its superclasses or just the object's singleton methods. So you can do `obj.methods(false)` to only get the singleton methods defined on `obj`.

If you want the methods defined by the object's class, but not those defined by its superclasses, you can get that by calling `instance_methods(false)` on the object's class, so it's `obj.class.instance_methods(false)`.

Answer (score 4):

I'm partial to `obj.methods.sort` but some of the other answers are better in certain cases as they describe

You can also use `obj.methods.sort.grep /foo/` to find method names matching the regexp.
This is helpful when you have an idea of what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You have a few options - `object.methods`, `object.public_methods`, `object.singleton_methods`... it depends on what you want. Since they both return an array, you might want to try something like:

```
# obj is the current object
parent = obj.class.superclass

methods = (obj.methods - parent.methods)
```

Comment: `whatever.methods` returns an `Array` in the version of Ruby i'm running.  Same with `whatever.public_methods`.